# Custom JSX.Element Implementation for Typescript Framework using Bun

Tags: typescript, jsx, bun

I'm trying to create a custom TypeScript framework to get a feel for the language and to use it in my personal projects. I'm following this tutorial on [Medium](https://mikeguoynes.medium.com/part-1-build-your-own-js-framework-from-scratch-f4e35d0dffa6), and I'm stuck on finding the definition of `JSX.Element`. Is there something I'm missing or do I even need it for the framework? Is it because of the Bun runtime? any help would be excellent. Thanks!